# how to decode an ascii string with backslash x \x codes

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-2.x

I am trying to decode from a Brazilian Portogese text:

> 'Demais Subfun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xb5es 12'

It should be

> 'Demais Subfunções 12'

```
>> a.decode('unicode_escape')
>> a.encode('unicode_escape')
>> a.decode('ascii')
>> a.encode('ascii')
```

all give:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

on the other hand this gives:

```
>> print a.encode('utf-8')
Demais Subfun├â┬º├â┬Áes 12

>> print a
Demais SubfunÃ§Ãµes 12
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have binary data that is **not** ASCII encoded. The `\xhh` codepoints indicate your data is encoded with a different codec, and you are seeing Python produce a *representation* of the data [using the `repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) that can be re-used as a Python literal that accurately lets you re-create the exact same value. This representation is very useful when debugging a program.

In other words, the `\xhh` escape sequences represent individual bytes, and the `hh` is the hex value of that byte. You have 4 bytes with hex values C3, A7, C3 and B5, that do not map to printable ASCII characters so Python uses the `\xhh` notation instead.

You instead have UTF-8 data, decode it as such:

```
>>> 'Demais Subfun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xb5es 12'.decode('utf8')
u'Demais Subfun\xe7\xf5es 12'
>>> print 'Demais Subfun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xb5es 12'.decode('utf8')
Demais Subfunções 12
```

The C3 A7 bytes together encode [U+00E7 LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA](https://codepoints.net/U+00E7), while the C3 B5 bytes encode [U+00F5 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH TILDE](https://codepoints.net/U+00F5).

ASCII happens to be a subset of the UTF-8 codec, which is why all the other letters can be represented as such in the Python `repr()` output.

Comment: How to avoid the use of 'print', i.e: write the decoded string inside a file?

Comment: @Slake: just write the decoded string to a file. Use `io.open(..., encoding='...')` in Python 2 to write Unicode data to a file.

Answer (score 1):

for `Python 3`: add `b` prefix, means `bytes`, then could use `decode`

```
>>> b"\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe4\xb8\x80\xe6\xad\xa5".decode("utf-8")
'下一步'
```

otherwise will error:

```
>>> "\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe4\xb8\x80\xe6\xad\xa5".decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```