# String compare in python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, char

I'm looking for duplicate files by compare the filenames.

However, I found some paths returned by `os.walk` contain escaped chars. For example, I may get `structure in the Earth\'s core.pdf` for one file and `structure in the Earth\xe2\x80\x99s core.pdf` for another.

```
In [1]: print 'structure in the Earth\'s core.pdf\nstructure in the Earth\xe2\x80\x99s core.pdf'
structure in the Earth's core.pdf
structure in the Earth’s core.pdf

In [2]: 'structure in the Earth\'s core.pdf' == 'structure in the Earth\xe2\x80\x99s core.pdf'
Out[2]: False
```

How do I deal with these cases?

====
Just to clarify the Q in response to the comments, there are also other situations for duplicate files like

- one filename containing more spaces than the other
- one filename separated by `-` while the other by `:`
- one filename containing Japanese/Chinese words and the other composed of digits and Japanese/Chinese words ...

Comment: they are two different characters... `'` is not equal to `’`. You replace one with the other or compare only the alpha-numerics of a given sentence.

Comment: They aren't the *same*, because they are using different encoding to create the same _general_ visual appearance. c.f. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761954/how-to-decode-an-ascii-string-with-backslash-x-x-codes) link for a similar discussion. They are different characters, as @bulbus notes. Fixing that is complicated, as it opens a can of worms about how many possible ways there are to say something that is intellectually similar, but not literally the same.

Comment: You might try boiling them down to "dictionary" representation, stripping out all the non-alphanumerics before comparing, and writing a report.

Comment: I know `'` is not `’`. But the two files are the same. For some reasons they were not named exactly the same. There are other situations like **one filename containing more spaces than the other**, **one filename separated by `-` while the other by `:`**, **some filenames containing non-letter chars as Japanese/Chinese words**... These's my difficulties now.

Comment: @bulbus  I don't have such a collection including all possible char pairs like this. Comparing letters and digits only may be a workaround.

Comment: @PaulHodges Thx, sounds like a solution, except for some files named mainly by non-English words. what do you mean by "writing a report"?

Comment: Just skip files with questionable matches until a human can evaluate them. For the most thorough and exact comparison, use `cmp` (the program - I guess the equivalent in python might be to read both into vars and compare them?)  If they are byte-exact, then the names don't matter. It's the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get the similarity of the strings instead of an exact match. Get the exact match can be problematic because of simple things like capitalization.

I suggest the following:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

s1 = "structure in the Earth\'s core.pdf"
s2 = "structure in the Earth\xe2\x80\x99s core.pdf"

matcher = SequenceMatcher()
matcher.set_seqs(s1, s2)
print(matcher.ratio())
# 0.9411764705882353
```

This result shows that the similarity between both strings is over 94%. You could define a threshold to delete or to review the items before deletion.